# Updating Solr field while posting .pdf document in Windows

Tags: windows, curl, solr

I want to post and index a PDF document while also updating a custom field I created. Basically, I want users to be able to enter tags before they upload a document.

I added a multiValued "tags" field to my managed-schema file:

```
<field name="tags" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

I have tried the curl commands for posting data, but they do not work for me. So far, this is the only command that I can post with that works:

```
java -Dauto -Dc=NameOfCore -Drecursive -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar  C:/Path/To/My/File.pdf
```

I tried this variation:

```
java -Dauto -Dc=NameOfCore -Drecursive -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar  C:/Path/To/My/File.pdf -params "literal.tags=test tag"
```

But this returns errors:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: No files or directories matching literal.tags=test tag
```

Is there a way to post and index a document while simultaneously updating a field on windows without the use of curl?