# Updating Solr Field during Post

Tags: search, solr

I use the Simple Post tool to post PDF documents to Solr with PowerShell. Is there a way to post the document and update a field attribute simultaneously?

For example, my current command is:

```
java -Dauto -Dc=NameOfCore -Drecursive -jar /post.jar "/path/to/my/file.pdf"
```

Is there a parameter or argument that I can add to the command where I can pass a value of a field?

I'm on Windows and Using Solr 6.5.1

Very Similar Question:

[Updating Solr field while posting .pdf document in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974956/updating-solr-field-while-posting-pdf-document-in-windows)

Comment: what do you mean, by saying updating the field?

Comment: Update a document field/attribute. For example, I have a "manufacturer" field and I would like to pass through a value for this field while posting the document.